how provide a site name to Google Search?
enter image description here
this is my meta code :
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>Login - {{ env('APP_NAME') }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="Printing Cashier Application to Increase Your Business Efficiency">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ env('APP_KEYWORD') }}">
<meta name="author" content="{{ env('APP_DEVELOPER') }}">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ env('APP_NAME') }}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ env('APP_URL') }}">

<!-- PWA  -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ asset('/') }}assets/images/settings/{{ $item->favicon }}">

<link rel="manifest" href="{{ asset('/manifest.json') }}">

<!-- Open Graph -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Aplikasi Kasir Percetakan | Khalid R">
<meta property="og:description" content="Printing Cashier Application to Increase Your Business Efficiency">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ env('APP_URL') }}">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ asset('/') }}assets/images/settings/{{ $item->favicon }}">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ env('APP_NAME') }}" />

provides the site name to Google Search, not the domain

Check in Google search console, and add your domain there. Even if you don't do it, Google's bots will add it for you unless you specifically asked them not to.

Don't use env() outside of config file https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/configuration#configuration-caching

With og:title you can show your website name:
  <meta property="og:title" content="Title of the Page" />


cant, still the domain name that is read by google
